# How to select with INNER JOIN, giving related but also unrelated records

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, sql-null

I have this two tables:

**users**

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | John  |
+----+-------+
| 2  | Peter |
+----+-------+
| 3  | Lucas |
+----+-------+
```

**gifts**

```
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| id | boy_id | type     | quantity |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| 1  | 1      | clothing | 3        |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| 2  | 2      | toy      | 1        |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| 3  | 2      | clothing | 2        |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
```

And Im trying to query "gifts received by the boys", something like this:

```
+-------+----------+----------+
| name  | type     | quantity |
+-------+----------+----------+
| John  | clothing | 3        |
+-------+----------+----------+
| Peter | toy      | 1        |
+-------+----------+----------+
| Peter | clothing | 2        |
+-------+----------+----------+
| Lucas | ""       | 0        |
+-------+----------+----------+
```

But I just know how to get relationed data with a query like this:

```
SELECT u.name, g.type, g.quantity FROM gifts g INNER JOIN users u ON g.boy_id = u.id
```

So, as Lucas is not in *gifts* table, Im getting the following:

```
+-------+----------+----------+
| name  | type     | quantity |
+-------+----------+----------+
| John  | clothing | 3        |
+-------+----------+----------+
| Peter | toy      | 1        |
+-------+----------+----------+
| Peter | clothing | 2        |
+-------+----------+----------+
```

So, how do I include peter to the result, filling type and quantity with a "" and zero if the boy haven't received a gift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just `left join`:

```
SELECT u.name, g.type, COALESCE(g.quantity, 0) quantity
FROM users u  
LEFT JOIN gifts g ON g.boy_id = u.id
```

Comment: Yep, this is what "outer joins" are for.